# sqlite update method using Cursor

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi  I am creating an sqlite helper file for my android project.  I have found a couple of tutorials on doing this but i am having an issue with retrieving values from the sqlite database.  I get the following error message:"Can not resolve constructor"

```
Event getEvent(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_EVENTNAME, KEY_EVENTTIME,
          KEY_EVENTDATE, KEY_EVENTLOCATION, KEY_EVENTADDRESS1, KEY_EVENTADDRESS2, KEY_EVENTCITY, KEY_EVENTSTATE, KEY_EVENTZIP, KEY_EVENTTYPE },
            KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Event event = new Event(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),
            cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9),
            cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11));

    //return event
    return  event;
}
```

The error is in the statement that starts with Event event = new Event....

I am not sure do if i need a cursor.getString(n) for each table column?

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

adding event file

```
  //empty contructor
public Event(){

}

public Event(int id, String _eventName, String _eventTime, String _eventDate, String _eventLocation, String _eventAddress1, String _eventAddress2, String _eventCity, String _eventState, int _eventZip, String _eventType) {
    this._id = id;
    this._eventName = _eventName;
    this._eventTime = _eventTime;
    this._eventDate = _eventDate;
    this._eventLocation = _eventLocation;
    this._eventAddress1 = _eventAddress1;
    this._eventAddress2 = _eventAddress2;
    this._eventCity = _eventCity;
    this._eventState = _eventState;
    this._eventZip = _eventZip;
    this._eventType = _eventType;
}

public  Event(String _eventName, String _eventTime, String _eventDate, String _eventLocation, String _eventAddress1, String _eventAddress2, String _eventCity, String _eventState, int _eventZip, String _eventType) {
    this._eventName = _eventName;
    this._eventTime = _eventTime;
    this._eventDate = _eventDate;
    this._eventLocation = _eventLocation;
    this._eventAddress1 = _eventAddress1;
    this._eventAddress2 = _eventAddress2;
    this._eventCity = _eventCity;
    this._eventState = _eventState;
    this._eventZip = _eventZip;
    this._eventType = _eventType;
}
```

Comment: Please paste your Event constructor. BTW: Better way to get value of column is `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(YOUR_KEY));`

Comment: oh dear, `Can not resolve constructor` means that compiler, wait for it, wait for it, can not resolve constructor.

Comment: @PetrDuchek I added my Event Constructor.   Thanks  I will try that way.

Comment: just count the number of parameters passed to the constructor with the number of parameters it can takes ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Selvin and @Pier That was part of the issue I had too many parameters and the other part was I didn't realize that you need cursor.getInt() instead cursor.getString for integers.

Thanks again